# Swift async/await - Ignore "Consider using asynchronous alternative function" warning

Tags: swift, async-await

I have some objective c networking code with completion handler for which swift has automatically generated an async version. I'm calling it at the end of an `async` function, but in this case I don't need to wait for it. I'm just passing `nil` for the completion handler. The compiler is giving me a warning:

`Consider using asynchronous alternative function`

```
Task {

  let foo = await bar() // Yes, using async/await here

  // Objc method. Completion is nil because I don't care about the result.
  noNeedToWaitForThis(completion: nil) // WARNING: Consider using asynchronous alternative function

}
```

Is there a swifty way to avoid this error? Or is the only option wrapping it in another function?

So far the best I've found is to just use a closure:

```
Task {
  ...
  {
    noNeedToWaitForThis(completion: nil) // No more warning
  }()
}
```

This is in Xcode 13.1.

[EDIT] Example objective c method with callback:

```
typedef void (^ResponseBlock)(BOOL success, id _Nullable object);
- (void)noNeedToWaitForThisWithCompletion:(nullable ResponseBlock)completion;
```

Comment: @Cristik Sure, I added an example.

Comment: could you solve this? :D because its very annoying that warning gives me anxiety

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Xcode 14.3, the easiest way to silence this warning was to use `let _ = ...`.

```
Task {
  ...
  let _ = noNeedToWaitForThis(completion: nil) // Warning is silenced
}
```

Unfortunately, now the only way seems to be an anonymous closure:

```
Task {
   { noNeedToWaitForThis(completion: nil) }() // Warning is silenced
}
```

Comment: I don't see the necessity **not** to use the `async` version. `Nullable` completion handlers are migrated to `@discardableResult`. And the `await` keyword doesn't mean necessarily that the callee does wait. And if there is an asynchronous task in the method it will be executed anyway.

Comment: @vadian Basically, we have a lot of objc networking code. In the cases where I use this I typically want to await e.g., `a`, `b`, and `c` and present that to the user, but just pre-fetch `d` so it's available later.